# Convert Hippo JCR datetime to Java format

Tags: java, datetime, jcr, hippocms

I use JCR Query to get some news from Hippo repository. and as result I getting date in this format:

```
2011-04-07T08:34:13.093Z
```

can someone tell me how can I convert it to like this:

```
07-04-2011 08:34
```

in a simple way.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
SimpleDateFormat hippoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date javaDate = hippoFormat.parse("2011-04-07T08:34:13.093Z", pp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input string you've described is formatted is an XSD dateTime. You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert to a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar, but you need to decide what to do with timezone, etc. The 'Z' at the end of the input string means it is 'Zulu' time -- i.e. UTC. When you convert, do you want the time in UTC or local timezone? If the input strings can also be non-UTC, you will need to code some additional logic.

Consider getting the source for [Jena framework's](http://jena.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) [XSDDateTime](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/datatypes/xsd/XSDDateTime.html) class.